# Discord.js 13 my bot doesn't show server name and shows "undefined" instead of username in embedded welcome messages

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, bots, embed

I would like to make welcome message embed bot but I have some problems. My Bot doesn't show server name and shows "undefined" instead of username in embedded welcome messages. This is not my code. I made couple of changes, because this code is from youtube guide that is outdated. I'm still beginner in coding so please be understandable.

Index.js:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client({ intents: ["GUILDS", "GUILD_MESSAGES" , "GUILD_MESSAGE_REACTIONS" , "DIRECT_MESSAGE_REACTIONS" , "GUILD_MEMBERS" ] , partials: ["MESSAGE" , "CHANNEL" , "REACTION"]  });


const { token } = require('./config.json')
const welcome = require('./commands/Main-Commands/Mod/welcome');


client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Ready.')
    
    setInterval(() => {
        const statuses = [
            `Tech Tip Cyber Videos`,
            `YouTube Tutorial`,
        ]

        const status = statuses[Math.floor(Math.random() * statuses.length)]
        client.user.setActivity(status, { type: "WATCHING"}) // Can Be WATCHING, STREAMING, LISTENING
    }, 2000) // Second You Want to Change Status, This Cahnges Every 2 Seconds

    welcome(client)
    
    
})
    


client.login(token)
```

welcome.js:

```
const { MessageEmbed, MessageAttachment } = require("discord.js")
const Canvas = require('canvas')
const { join } = require("path")
const user = require('discord.js')
const prefix = '+'
module.exports = (client) => {
    client.on('guildMemberAdd', async member => {
        // console.log(member) // If You Want The User Info in Console Who Joined Server Then You Can Add This Line. // Optional

        const welcome = '938780971568889876' // Welcome Channel
        const rules = '938781016502456380' // Rules Channel

        if(!member.guild) return

        const canvas = Canvas.createCanvas(1770, 635) // Create Canvas Of Your Wish
        const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d') // 2d Only For Now
        const background = await Canvas.loadImage(join(__dirname, '../../../Images', 'welcome.png')) // BackGround Image
        ctx.drawImage(background, 0 ,0, canvas.width, canvas.height) // Setting BackGround Image
        ctx.strokeStyle = '#FFFFFF' // Keep Color As Nothing

        ctx.strokeRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
        var name = `${member.user.username}` // UserName Of User Who Joined
        if(name.length >= 16) { // If Name Is To Long(More Then 16)
            ctx.font = 'bold 100px Sans' // Defining Size, Font
            ctx.fillStyle = '#0FEEF3' // Keep Color Of UserName
            ctx.fillText(name, 680, canvas.height / 2 - 1) // 720 Is Width From Left To Right
        } else { // If UserName Is Smaller Then 16 Then...
            ctx.font = 'bold 130px Sans' // Defining Size, Font
            ctx.fillStyle = '#0FEEF3' // Keep Color Of UserName
            ctx.fillText(name, 680, canvas.height / 2 - 1) // 720 Is Width From Left To Right // You Can Change According To Your Will
        }

        var discrim = `#${member.user.discriminator}` // Discriminator Of User
        ctx.font = 'bold 60px Sans'  // Defining Size, Font
        ctx.fillStyle = '#FA9448' // Keep Color Of Discriminator
        ctx.fillText(discrim, 680, canvas.height / 2 + 70) // You Can Change According To Your Will

        var server = `Welcome To ${member.guild.name}` 
        ctx.font = 'bold 80px Sans'  // Defining Size, Font
        ctx.fillStyle = '#21FBA1' // Keep Color Of Discriminator
        ctx.fillText(server, 670, canvas.height / 2 - 150) // You Can Change According To Your Will

        var count = `Member #${member.guild.memberCount}th`
        ctx.font = 'bold 60px Sans'  // Defining Size, Font
        ctx.fillStyle = '#21FBA1' // Keep Color Of Discriminator
        ctx.fillText(count, 680, canvas.height / 2 + 160) // You Can Change According To Your Will

        ctx.beginPath()
        ctx.arc(315, canvas.height / 2, 250, 0, Math.PI * 2, true) // Avatar Of User
        ctx.closePath()
        ctx.clip() // Make Avatar As Circle, By Default Its Square

        const avatar = await Canvas.loadImage(member.user.displayAvatarURL({ format: 'png' })) // Get Users Avatar
        ctx.drawImage(avatar, 65, canvas.height / 2- 250, 500 , 500) // Adjusting Avatar In Circle Of Image

        const attachment = new MessageAttachment(canvas.toBuffer(), 'welcome.png') // Send As Attachment

        const embed = new MessageEmbed() // Send As Embed
        .setAuthor({ name: `${user.tag}`, iconURL: member.user.displayAvatarURL()})
        .setDescription(`
        Welcome To **$member.guild.name** <@${member.id}>
        Please Check <#${rules}>        
        `)
        .setImage('attachment://welcome.png')
        .setColor('RANDOM')
        const channel = member.guild.channels.cache.get(welcome) // Get Welcome Channel
       

        channel.send({ embeds: [embed], files: [attachment]})

       

        client.on('messageCreate', message => {
            const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
            const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
        
                
     
        })
    })
}
```

If someone is able to help me, please explain what is wrong with my code and what should I change to make it work.
**Please check the screenshot** [scr1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LR90C.png)

I would like "undefined" to show the username and instead $member.guild.name the server name

Comment: I solved it. Here's pastebin for welcome.js if someone had similar problem: https://pastebin.com/S91G3ieS I can't post it right here (too long message)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please do not edit solution announcements into the question. Accept (i.e. click the "tick" next to it) one of the existing answer, if there are any. You can also create your own answer, and even accept it, if your solution is not yet covered by an existing answer. Compare https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer